# Improve existing alias to dynamically replace command line text

Tags: command-line, alias

I have an alias in `.bashrc` like this:

```
alias ylog = "yarn logs -applicationId"
```

This works well when I do `ylog application_123`.

Sometimes, my job names come in the form of `job_123` instead of `application_123` and in order to get `ylog` I need to manually replace the text "job" by "application" in my command line.

Is it possible to improve the alias so that the following happens:

- `ylog job_123` resolves to `ylog application_123`
- `ylog application_123` resolves to `ylog application_123`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash does not allow parameters in aliases, so you need to define and use a function, e.g.:

```
ylog() {
    yarn logs -applicationId "${1/#job_/application_}"
}
```

Comment: perfect this works great!